# energy difference uniqueness in hydrogen atom

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atomic-physics, hydrogen

Is the energy difference between two energy levels unique for that particular pair of levels for a hydrogen atom ?
If so how can one prove it?

Comment: Good question, I came across this in past but never found an answer. Perhaps it would help others to understand the question if you formulated it as a problem from the theory of natural numbers.

Comment: If I understand right: I believe you are asking whether, using the [Dirac formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen-like_atom#Solution_to_Dirac_equation) for the energy levels $E_{n\,j}  = \mu c^2\left(1+\left[\dfrac{Z\alpha}{n-|k|+\sqrt{k^2-Z^2\alpha^2}}\right]^2\right)^{-1/2}$ and then proving $E_{n\,j}$ is unique for each pair$(n,j)\in \mathbb{Z}_0^+\times \mathbb{Z}_0^+$? If so, you might try Maths SE. This is a harder problem than it looks.

Comment: Why bother with the Dirac formula, it is messy and contains $\alpha$ which is not known to be simple number. More interesting is the Schroedinger non-relativistic case : for given $\Delta E$, find all $n,m$ such that $ \Delta E = \frac{1}{n^2}- \frac{1}{m^2}$.